# How to solve the problem of invalid configuration file package prompted by the error in the launched App Store?

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I am a Windows system, and there is no xcode. The package is packaged with the uniapp. After uploading the IPA, it is not displayed. The second one
The figure shows the message prompt. Error content:
Dear Developer
We identified one or more issues with a recent deliverv for your app
"zhihuiyunwei" 1.0.0 (100). Please correct the following issues, then upload
Again We found one or more problems with your recently delivered application "zhihuiyunwei" 1.0.0 (100). Please correct to
Next question, and then upload again.
ITMS-90161: Invalid Provisioning Profile-The provisioning profile included in
the bundle com.zhukaoplus. ops [Payload/HBuilderapp]is invalid. Missing code-
signing certificate].  A Distribution Provisioning profile should be used when
submitting apps to the App Store.  For more information, visit the ios Developer
Portal.
ITMS-90161: Invalid configuration file - configuration file contained in package comzhukaopus.
Ops [Payload/HBuilder. app] is invalid. [Missing code signing certificate]. When submitting apps to the Store, you should use distribution
Configuration file. For more information, please visit the iOS Developer Portal.
Best regards
Best regards,
The App Store Team
AppStore Team
Attached pictures:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check or reconfigure the following contents when packaging with Hbild
1.bundle id: com.zhukaoplus. The ops should be consistent with the profile file
2. When publishing the app store, use the release certificate instead of the development certificate;
Repack and try